# In Python Pandas, how do I combine two columns containing strings using if/else statement or similar?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, if-statement

I have created a pandas dataframe from an excel file where first two columns are:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'0':['','','Location Code','pH','Ag','Alkalinity'], '1':['Lab Id','Collection Date','','','µg/L','mg/L']})
```

which looks like this:

```
         df[0]           df[1]
                        Lab Id
               Collection Date
Location Code                 
           pH                 
           Ag             µg/L
   Alkalinity             mg/L
```

I want to merge these columns into one that looks like this:

```
           df[0]
          Lab Id
 Collection Date
   Location Code
              pH
        Ag (µg/L)
Alkalinity (mg/L)
```

I believe I need a control statement before combining df[0] and df[1] which would appear like this:

```
if **there is a blank space in either column, then it performs**:
   df[0] = df[0].astype(str)+df[1].astype(str)
else:
   df[0] = df[0].astype(str)+' ('+df[1].astype(str)+')'
```

but I am not sure how to write the if statement. Could anyone please guide me here.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

We can try `np.select`

```
cond=[(df['0']=='') & (df['1']!=''), (df['0']!='') & (df['1']==''), (df['0']!='') & (df['1'] !='')]
val=[df['1'], df['0'], df['0']+ '('+df['1']+')']
df['new']=np.select(cond,val)
df
               0                1               new
0                          Lab Id            Lab Id
1                 Collection Date   Collection Date
2  Location Code                      Location Code
3             pH                                 pH
4             Ag             µg/L          Ag(µg/L)
5     Alkalinity             mg/L  Alkalinity(mg/L)
```

Comment: Thanks @YOBEN_S. It worked! I just changed `df['0']` to `df[0]` and so on. Also, I wanted the newly merged column `df['new']` to replace `df[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

if value is Na, maybe:

```
df['result'] = df[0].fillna(df[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

This works using `numpy where`, and the string concatenation assumption is based on the data shared :

```
df.assign(
    merger=np.where(
        df["1"].str.endswith("/L"),
        df["0"].str.cat(df["1"], "(").add(")"),
        df["0"].str.cat(df["1"], ""),
    )
)

       0                 1              merger
0                      Lab Id           Lab Id
1                      Collection Date  Collection Date
2   Location Code                       Location Code
3   pH                                   pH
4   Ag                 µg/L              Ag(µg/L)
5   Alkalinity  mg/L                     Alkalinity(mg/L)
```

Or, you could just assign it to "0", if that is what you are after :

```
df["0"] = np.where(
    df["1"].str.endswith("/L"),
    df["0"].str.cat(df["1"], "(").add(")"),
    df["0"].str.cat(df["1"], ""),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

First you replace values you are going to `concat` with the value + '()'

```
df['1'].loc[df.replace('', np.nan).notnull().all(axis =1 )] = '(' + df['1'] + ')'
```

Now we fill in missing values with `bfill` and `ffill`

```
df = df.replace('', np.nan).bfill(axis = 1).ffill(axis = 1)
```

Only thing remaining, is to merge values wherever we have brackets

```
 df.loc[:, 'merge'] = np.where(df['1'].str.endswith(')'), df['0'] + df['1'], df['1'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Test if empty value at least in one column `0,1` by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and then join both columns like in your answer in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0:['','','Location Code','pH','Ag','Alkalinity'], 
                   1:['Lab Id','Collection Date','','',u'µg/L','mg/L']})


print (df[[0,1]].eq(''))
       0      1
0   True  False
1   True  False
2  False   True
3  False   True
4  False  False
5  False  False

print (df[[0,1]].eq('').any(axis=1))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

```
df[0] = np.where(df[[0,1]].eq('').any(axis=1), 
                 df[0].astype(str)+df[1].astype(str),
                 df[0].astype(str)+' ('+df[1].astype(str)+')')
print (df)
                   0                1
0             Lab Id           Lab Id
1    Collection Date  Collection Date
2      Location Code                 
3                 pH                 
4          Ag (µg/L)             µg/L
5  Alkalinity (mg/L)             mg/L
```